# D3: Convert scale level of the time scale to time period, like: day, week or month?

Tags: d3.js, scale

Having the current scale level for the time scale from *d3.event.scale* (*e.g. `0.5` or `1.5`*), is there any rule of how to convert it to human readable form, like - *day*, *week*, *month* or *year*?

**UPDATE:**

Here is a draft of what I'm working on: http://cdpn.io/gzfyj. I'm basically seeking for a way to get time boundaries after zooming or panning and the zoom factor in above mentioned identifiers.

Comment: Can you give an example of what actual coordinates of your scale are? After zooming, will doing `var width = x.scale().extent(); var dur = width[1] - width[0];` and converting `dur` from milliseconds to proper  time periods will not suffice?

Comment: Well if after those operations I'll get milliseconds, then probably it will suffice. If you will come up with an actual example I could accept it as answer.

Comment: Basically I want to know if time scale is currently zoomed out to days, months or years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After zooming,

```
var width = x.domain(); 
var dur = width[1] - width[0];
```

will return the `width` of the scale in `milliseconds`. Then this duration can be converted to any form you like.

---

This is an working example where I have used `moment.js` to *humanize* the duration at the bottom of the graph: http://codepen.io/musically_ut/pen/DJqtw

```
  var ext = x.domain();
  var duration = moment.duration(ext[1] - ext[0]).humanize();

  chart
    .select("text.duration")
    .text(duration);
```